# MapBox Studio - Reverse Character Strings

Tags: mapbox, cartocss

I am working on a project in MapBox studio where I had to flip all the labels 180° that were on lines. Since its not possible to use text-orientation for labels on lines, I flipped the font file 180 degrees.

I now need to reverse the character strings before they are rendered. Is there a way to do this in MapBox Studio using CartoCSS ?

Something like

```
direction:rtl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are you sourcing your data from?  And are you trying to turn something like `abcd` into `dcba`?

If you're sourcing from a PostgreSQL database, there's the [reverse()](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Reverse_string) function for strings.

If you're sourcing from a shapefile, it shouldn't be too hard to write a function useing a spreadsheet application (e.g. OpenLibre) that copies one of the columns in the dbf into a new reversed column.

...but to actually answer your question directly: no, I'm pretty sure there is not a way to reverse text using cartocss.  sounds like more of a candidate for a data preprocessing step.

Comment: I am using Mapbox Studio and all the data is coming from the MapBox streets source. If I cannot reverse the Mapbox sourced data then I'll likely have to source my own

Comment: Yeah, in that case, you'll have to source your own.